# jquery build select and set the selected option based on value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that builds a select inside a loop for a table:

```
var index = 0;
                        var options = data.data.Options;
                        var targets = data.data.Targets;

                        var targetsSelectOptions = '<option></option>';
                        $.each(targets, function () {
                         
                            targetsSelectOptions += '<option val="' + this.Id + '">' + this.Description + '</option>';
                        });

                        $.each(options, function () {

                            $('#dtoptions > tbody').append(
                                '<tr>'
                                + '<td style="width:100px;"><input type="text" class="form-control input-sm " id="param_' + index + '" value="' + this.Parameter + '"></td>'
                                + '<td><select id="targetId_'+ index + '" required class="form-control input-sm">' + targetsSelectOptions + '</select></td>'
                                + '<td style="width:60px;"><select id="next_'+ index +'" required class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>'
                                + '<td style="width:35px;"><a href="#" data-id="btn-delete" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light"><i class="mdi mdi-delete"></i></a></td>'
                                + '</tr>'
                            );

                            $('#targetId_' + index).val(this.TargetId);

                            index++;
                        });
```

The select is created correctly but when I want to set the selected option:

```
 $('#targetId_' + index).val(this.TargetId);
```

It doesn't select anything. Any clue?

Comment: You don't need to track `index`, because it's passed as the first argument in the `$.each()` call. Same for the current working item in your loop, it's the second argument. Try using those instead of the `this` keyword; `$.each(targets, function(index, item)  { ... })`, where index is index, and item is one of the items in the array you're looping over.

Comment: Hi, here `<option val="' + this.Id + '">` val should be `value` correct that it should work.

Comment: Lol, that was the issue :) copy and paste is always a bad habit. Thansk a lot